# Помогите переделать скрипт

Tags: javascript

Помогите переделать скрипт чтоб результат выводился так ЧАС:МИНУТ:СЕК

```js
var TIMEOUT = 15; // sec

function showTime(t) {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (t != 0) ? t : "";
}

function timer(t) {
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    if (t == undefined)
        t = TIMEOUT;
    showTime(t);
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        --t;
        showTime(t);
        if (t <= 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function onClick() {
    document.cookie = "timeout=" + new Date();
    timer();
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(
        new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)")
    );
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}

function onLoad() {
    var prevStartTime = new Date(getCookie("timeout"));
    var delta = TIMEOUT - Math.round((new Date() - prevStartTime) / 1000);
    if (delta > 0) {
        timer(delta);
    }
}
```

```html
<body onload="onLoad();">
    <button id="btn" onclick="onClick();">Click me!</button>
    <br />
    <span id="time"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: какой скрипт-то нужно переделать?

Comment: не могу на данный скрипт добавить час и минуты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
    var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10); 
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
}
```

Использовать так

```
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (t != 0) ? ("" + t).toHHMMSS() : "";
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все так как я хотел.

Comment: В таком случае пометьте ответ как подходящий, нажав на галочку )